# how do I dynamically(?) add fields in Django model?

Tags: django

So I'm a newbie in Django, and having trouble with model.
I'm wondering if creating additional field every time a user does certain action (e.g., click (+) button) is possible. So below is the field that I want the user to add as many as he/she wants.
models.py

```
class SimpleInput(models.Model):
    each_input = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I have the (+) button in my html file, as well as JavaScript code that enables the function--adding fields with id's increasing by +1. But I'm not sure how I can connect this with model. 
I very much appreciate your help. Thanks :)

For your information, I'm attaching the JS code.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var addNum = 0;
            $("#addButton").click(function(){
                var currentId = $("#simple_input"+addNum.toString()); 
                var newId = currentId.clone(); 
                newId.attr('value', '');
                newId.attr('class', "addedLine");
                newId.attr('id', "simple_input"+(addNum+1).toString()).prependTo(".ED_addedHere");
                addNum = addNum +1;
            });
            });
```

Comment: Model fields form the basis of your database table structure, so no, this isn't realistic. You're looking for a one-to-many foreign key relationship instead.

Comment: Oh, so would it be impossible to flexibly add/remove input fields by user's action?

Comment: It doesn't look like adding new **fields** to the model is what you need anyway. It looks like you're just letting the user add more **rows** (more `SimpleInput` instances) at once. In which case you might want to take a look at Django [**formsets**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: @dirkgroten Oh this is new to me. Thanks a lot :)